# How to align two buttons horizontally without changing the parent's display style

Tags: html, css

I need to have two buttons elements inside an `h2` element, I want the two buttons to be in the same line, aligned horizontally and not one above another, with some blank space between the title and them but I don't want to change the `h2` parent display or styles, what other way can I achieve this? Is it possible?

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8x 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 
 .btn--small {
   padding: 4px 16px;
 }
```

```html
<h2 id="myId">Amazing title
  <div class="video" data-link="jksaj898" data-params="modestbranding=1&amp;am;showinfo=0&amp;vq=720&amp;color=white&amp;theme=light&amp;fs=1">
    <button class="play-button btn btn--small">
      <use xlink:href="#video-play">
      </use>WATCH IT
    </button>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn--small">REGISTER</button>
 </h2>
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8x 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.btn--small {
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

.button-div {
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myId">Amazing title
  <div class="button_div">
    <div class="video" data-link="jksaj898" data-params="modestbranding=1p;fs=1">
      <button class="play-button btn btn--small">
        <use xlink:href="#video-play">
        </use>WATCH IT
       </button>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn--small">REGISTER</button>
  </div>
 </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML and put both buttons inside your `.video` div.

```css
#myId {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8x 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.btn--small {
  padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myId">Amazing title
  <div class="video" data-link="jksaj898" data-params="modestbranding=1&amp;am;showinfo=0&amp;vq=720&amp;color=white&amp;theme=light&amp;fs=1">
    <button class="play-button btn btn--small">
      <use xlink:href="#video-play">
      </use>WATCH IT
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn--small">REGISTER</button>
  </div>

</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm adding `.video` div dynamically so it might not exist sometimes, I cannot put one of the buttons inside that one if it doesn't exist. What I'm trying to do now is just add another `div` element for the buttons inside the `h2`. I gave to this new div `display: inline-flex` but now, in certain screen sizes the buttons appear inline with the text on the `h2` instead of below, I tried giving `display:block` to the `h2` element but no luck. I have added a new code snippet with I'm trying to do now

Answer (score 0):

**FLoat** : The float property specifies whether or not an element should float.

Just add `float` property in your css

```
.btn--small {
    float:left;
    padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

```css
 

I need to have two buttons elements inside an h2 element, I want the two buttons to be in the same line, aligned horizontally and not one above another, with some blank space between the title and them but I don't want to change the h2 parent display or styles, what other way can I achieve this? Is it possible?

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8x 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 
 .btn--small {
   padding: 4px 16px;
 }

<h2 id="myId">Amazing title
  <div class="video" data-link="jksaj898" data-params="modestbranding=1&amp;am;showinfo=0&amp;vq=720&amp;color=white&amp;theme=light&amp;fs=1">
    <button class="play-button btn btn--small">
      <use xlink:href="#video-play">
      </use>WATCH IT
    </button>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn--small">REGISTER</button>
 </h2>

Full page

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8x 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 1em;

}

.btn--small {
  float:left;
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

.button-div {
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myId">Amazing title
  <div class="video" data-link="jksaj898" data-params="modestbranding=1&amp;am;showinfo=0&amp;vq=720&amp;color=white&amp;theme=light&amp;fs=1">
    <button class="play-button btn btn--small">
      <use xlink:href="#video-play">
      </use>WATCH IT
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn--small">REGISTER</button>
  </div>

</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use or add `float: left` to your class `.btn`

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fkw8c9az/